# Find all polynomials $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $p(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb R $ and $p(\mathbb{C - R}) \subset \mathbb{C - R }$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Find all polynomials $p(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $p(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb R $ and $p(\mathbb{C - R}) \subset \mathbb{C - R }$.

Note that  $ \mathbb C =\{a+bi\mid a,b \in\mathbb R \}$.

For example let $0 \neq a_0,c_0 \in\mathbb R $ then $p(x)=a_0x +c_0$ is one answer.

Answer (score 10):

You're on exactly the right track.

First, let us note that $p$ and $\overline{p}$ agree on $\mathbb{R}$, since $p(x) = \overline{p(x)} = \overline{p}({\overline{x}}) = \overline{p}(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since they agree on infinitely many values, we have $p = \overline{p}$; thus, $p$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. That is, $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

Let us evaluate $p$ a bit further. Clearly, we cannot have that $p$ is a constant polynomial, since then we would have, for example, $p(i) = p(0) \in \mathbb{R}$, which is forbidden.

So $\deg(p) > 0$. We now consider two cases.

First, suppose the degree of $p$ is even. In this case, $\inf\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} p(x)$ exists. Let $w = \inf\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} p(x)$. Consider $q(x) = p(x) - w - 1$. Now $\deg(q) = \deg(p) > 0$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, $q$ has a root; call it $r$. Clearly, $r \notin \mathbb{R}$. Then $p(r) \in \mathbb{R}$, but $r \notin \mathbb{R}$. This goes against the requirement that $p(\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Now suppose the degree of $p$ is odd. We can show that for sufficiently large $w$, there is exactly one $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p(r) = w$, and also that $w$ is not a multiple root. This is because for sufficiently large or small $x$, $p’(x) > 0$. Therefore, we know that $p$ must be of degree 1, since otherwise, there would be a second, necessarily non-real solution to $p(r) = w$, which is impossible.

So we know that $p$ is a degree-one polynomial in $\mathbb{R}(x)$. In other words, the solutions you laid out in your question are the only ones.

Comment: The early parts are great. I'm not sure about the ending though. Why does it follow that $q(x)$ is non-real for every non-real $x$? We know that, for example, $p(i)=(i-r)q(i)$ must be non-real, but this is true even if $q(i)$ is real and non-zero. However, for odd degree polynomial $p(x)$ we do know (from its plot for real values $x$) that it attains very large real values only once. So, again, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, the other roots of $p(x)=M$, $M$ very large, must be complex. Unless $p(x)$ is linear, those other roots exist

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are correct that my original method didn’t work. I have fixed the proof.

Comment: I think the whole case distinction would be summed up in the *Lemma*: For any $p(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ there exists a ("vertical shift") $m \in \mathbb R$ such that $p(x)+m$ has $\le 1$ real roots.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg That is a good summation (assuming we clarify we’re counting multiplicity), but I think the proof would probably require doing case analysis on the degree of $p$.

Comment: Right, but alternatively this works: For $deg(p) \ge 2$, there exists $K:=[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ such that $\lvert p'(x) \rvert \ge 1$ for $x \notin K$. Let $m := 1-\min\{p(x):x \in K\}$. By definition, $p(x) +m$ has no zero on $K$; by the MVT, it can have at most one single root on $(-\infty, a)$ and at most one single root on $(b, \infty)$. So we get a contradiction for $deg(p)\ge 3$. The quadratic case is left to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a geometrically minded proof using some topological analysis (e.g. from Beardon's *Complex Analysis*).  We can assume $p$ has degree $d \gt 0$ since a constant polynomial has a single point in its image that cannot be both real and non-real thus $p$ is non-constant.

**(i)** The requirement $p(\mathbb{C - R}) \subset \mathbb{C - R }$ implies each half plane of $p(\mathbb{C - R})$ is mapped to a half plane (since connectedness is preserved under continuous maps).

*Geometrically what this means:* is if we consider a counter-clockwise simple closed curve whose image is a circle (with large enough radius) starting at 1, then computing the winding number around zero under the image of $p$ will count the number of roots and hence gives us $d$; but (i) tells us if we split said curve under the image of $p$ into halves, the first half begins and ends on the real line and is always contained in a single closed half plane, hence the angle swept by the curve must equal $\pm 180$ degrees or $0$ degrees; the same applies for the second half of the curve; conclusion: the original closed curve must wind around the origin 0 or 1 times. Since $d\gt 0$ this tells us $d=1$.

---

Consider the closed curve
$\gamma: [0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by
$\gamma(t)=r\cdot \exp(2 \pi \cdot i \cdot t)$
for large enough $r$ (i.e. so $r$ is larger than the modulus of all of the $d$ roots of $p$)
(with $p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k z^k$, e.g. in the case of monic $p$, then $r\geq 2+ \sum_{k=0}^d \vert a_k\vert$ works).

and now split the closed curve $\gamma$ into two halves, $\gamma_1:[0,\frac{1}{2}]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ and $\gamma_2:[\frac{1}{2},1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$
$\gamma_1(t) =r\cdot \exp(2 \pi \cdot i \cdot t)$ i.e. is $= \gamma_{\big\vert[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$, i.e. $\gamma$ restricted to the first half of the closed interval,  and
$\gamma_2(t) =r\cdot \exp(2\pi \cdot i \cdot t)$ i.e. $= \gamma_{\big\vert[\frac{1}{2},1]}$

Then computing the winding number of $p\circ \gamma$ which counts the roots and hence the degree
$d = n\big(p\circ \gamma, 0\big) = n\big(p\circ \gamma_1, 0\big) +n\big(p\circ \gamma_2, 0\big) \leq \vert n\big(p\circ \gamma_1, 0\big)\vert  +\vert n\big(p\circ \gamma_2, 0\big)\vert\lt 2 $
since $\vert n\big(p\circ \gamma_1, 0\big)\vert \lt 1$  and  $ \vert n\big(p\circ \gamma_2, 0\big)\vert \lt 1$

that is, $p\circ \gamma_1$ is non-zero (since $r$ is large enough) and stays in the same closed half-plane hence it never intersects one of the purely imaginary half lines i.e. never intersects the ray (with $t\geq 0$) given by
(a) $t\cdot \exp\big(i\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$ or (b) $t\cdot \exp\big(i\cdot\frac{3\pi}{2}\big)$.  Hence the winding number has modulus strictly $\lt 1$.  (This is property I5 in chapter 7, section 3 of Beardon for those interested). And the same bounding argument holds for $p\circ \gamma_2$.  Conclude: $0\lt d\lt 2\implies d= 1$.